# How can I find who modified my list view?

Tags: sharepoint-list

Is there a way to tell who has modified a list view?

Relatedly, using out-of-the-box settings in Sharepoint, I do not see a way to keep list views from being changed by a specific group of users. Am I overlooking this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer to see who last modified a view.
In SPD click on All Files (left nav), select the list/library you want to check, then click on Forms. In the Forms folder, you will see a list of Views and who last modified them.  You should be able to view this same info using PowerShell.

You can use permissions to control who can modify views.

Comment: Thank you, Taco_Buffet. I'll take a look at SPD. I dug a little deeper and I think you're referring to Permission Levels. That's sounds promising. Thanks again!